# How to override the current registration email tempalate with custom email template in worpdress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

How can we disable the current email template of registration in wordpress and override with the new custom new email template in wordpress. If anyone know please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_new_user_notification_email` filter as defined [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notificatio). This will allow you to override the default email message sent.

You can also see an implementation of it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/#div-comment-3130).

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Custom register email
 */
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
 
    $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
    $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    $login_url  = wp_login_url();
    $message  = __( 'Hi there,' ) . "/r/n/r/n";
    $message .= sprintf( __( "Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:" ), get_option('blogname') ) . "/r/n/r/n";
    $message .= wp_login_url() . "/r/n";
    $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "/r/n";
    $message .= sprintf( __('Email: %s'), $user_email ) . "/r/n";
    $message .= __( 'Password: The one you entered in the registration form. (For security reason, we save encripted password)' ) . "/r/n/r/n";
    $message .= sprintf( __('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email') ) . "/r/n/r/n";
    $message .= __( 'bye!' );
 
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] Your credentials.', $blogname );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;
 
    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).